# Finding range of Domain where there is only one solution

Tags: functions, exponential-function, exponentiation

Given
$$f(x) = \left(2^{x}-1-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ how to find all values of $x$ such that there
is only one $y$ such that $f(x)=y $ $$$$
or in other terms when $f^{-1}(y)$ has only 1 solution.

without using the lambert function.

Comment: What steps have you taken so far?

Comment: @questionasker i tried to explicit the x such that x=(f(y)) but i cant find the inverse function

Comment: If $f(x)$ is defined on $[a,b]$ then $f(x)$ will have an inverse function throughout $[a,b] \iff f(x)$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing on $[a,b].$  Therefore, the first step would be to investigate $f'(x)$ and (perhaps) $f''(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per definition $\operatorname f(x)$ exists only for $x$ belonging to $R$ \ ${0}$.

So why do you want to avoid using the Lambert function? You mean $W(x) = xe^x$. Right?
Just for my understanding...

Further it seems, without having proven this, from the function graph that the solution interval such as $\operatorname f(x) = y$ is unique in not the wohle definition interval because you can see counter-examples in the graph.

[image]

Calculate $f'(x)$ first and see whether f is strictly increasing. Then you would be able to proove my assumptions.

If the number derived from a function is positive over an interval, this function will increase over that same interval. Conversely, if it is negative, it will be decreasing. When the derived number is zero at one point, the curve admits a horizontal tangent in this.

Let's continue. Here $f'(x) = 2^x.\operatorname ln(2) + 1/x²$

which means that $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ belonging to $R$ \ ${0}$.

Therefore the function $f$ is strictly increasing respectively over $R^+$ \ ${0}$ and $R^-$ \ ${0}$

Comment: thank you i calculated $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -1$. the function is strictly increasing everywhere in the domain so how do i understand from this that from x<=1 , there is only one value for y?..

Comment: but i understand now, i should divide the function into 2 function, one for x<0, and one for x>0, and to see where the maximum, and minimum values of y for each function is including infinity. then comparing the 2 i would find the result , right?

Comment: delimit the definition domain and investigate partial inverses (you can read in Wikepedia for exp. about partial inerses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function )

Comment: Your function is obviously not a bijection.

Comment: I edited my answer. Do you still have questions? Did you already prove that for x<-1 you have a unique y?

Comment: i can prove it by looking at the graph calculating the $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = -1$ while doing $\lim_{x \to 0-} f(x) = +\infty$ so knowing that on the "left" part of the graph  **$-1<y<=\infty$**.. while calculating the limits of the right part of the graph  $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x) = -\infty$ and   $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ so it is that **$-\infty<=y<=\infty$**. comparing the values of y in the left part and right part, i see the diffrence at -1 so is prooved..but i was wondering is not a faster way?

Comment: I would have proven this by calculating the partial inverse for different intervals. You would get among others a distinction of cases with x<-1 and x>-1 while calculating.